# php not saving details to db from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm using Facebook's Javascript SDK and I'm unable to save the user's basic details to my database using Ajax and PHP. I've already tried console.log in my ajax to see what details are being pass onto and it is correct. I am guessing this is an issue with my PHP file. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            var data = {
                    name: response.first_name + response.last_name,
                    email: response.email,
                    gender: response.gender
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.lookingfour.com/std.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    console.log('Successful login for: ' + data);
                    alert('success');;
                }
            });
        });

    }
```

Here's my PHP file

std.php

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('lookingfour.com', 'lookfoursand', 'look4sandbox');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('lookfoursandbox', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

$name =  $_POST['name'];
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$gender =  $_POST['gender'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table(id, user_name, user_email, user_gender)   
VALUES(NULL,'$name','$email','$gender')";

if(!mysql_query($sql))
{
die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($link);

//}

?>
```

Double checked the database details and it is not the issue here.

UPDATE: FIXED IT BY COMBINING "dann" and "zpr"'s SUGGESTIONS TO MY QUESTION. IM JUST NOT SURE HOW TO GIVE 2 CORRECT ANSWERS FOR THE 2 OF YOU BUT THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: I would just assign Object literal to the `data` property, otherwise, you'll have to `encodeURIComponent()`  on `name` and `email`, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the variables in as query strings and trying to read them as `POST` vars. Instead of separating them by `&`s, make them into a **JSON** object, and pass that to your ajax call, with method POST specified.
A sample JSON object would be something like this:

```
var data = {      
  name: name,      
  email: email,      
  gender: gender    
}
```

Then you would pass this into your ajax call as the data:

```
$.ajax({      
  method: POST,      
  data: data,      
  ...    
)};
```

Also note the `method: POST`, I don't think there is a valid property called "type".

Edit: `type` is apparently a valid alias for `method`.

Comment: console now shows Successful login for: [object Object] but still doesnt save anything

Comment: Try inspecting the `POST` vars on the server-side with `printr` or `echo` or something

Comment: it shows blank. but on network dev tools it shows std.php= with the values

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific? In the network tab of dev tools you see the correct data being transmitted?

Comment: Yes. from there I can see this. http://www.lookingfour.com/std.php?name=RicCepeda&email=rcepeda62%40yahoo.com&gender=male&_=1450325196343 but it is not being saved to db

Comment: fixed. Apparently, forgot to bring method back to 'type' and it fixed it.

Comment: Ah, sorry bout that, maybe an old version of jQuery. Glad it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name+'&email='+email+'&gender='+gender;

 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://www.lookingfour.com/std.php',
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function()
      {
         alert('success');
      }
    });

//php file
$name=mysql_escape_String($_POST['name']);
$email=mysql_escape_String($_POST['email']);
$gender=mysql_escape_String($_POST['gender']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "std.php",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email, 
                    gender: gender
                },
                success: function () {
                    console.log('Successful login for: ' + name + email + gender);
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
```

Comment: tried this but didn't work. still no entry to database.

Comment: Please debug using chrome's developer tools. on the network tab, you should see the POST ajax request. inspect if the Form Data is sent with the POST

Comment: hi dann, tried that and found the std.php=name etc.... and it says <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'lookfoursand'@'web349.webfaction.com' (using password: YES) in <b>/home/lookfouradmn/webapps/lookingfoursandbox/std.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'lookfoursand'@'web349.webfaction.com' (using password: YES)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the correct details as I've double checked now and before and it's correct

Comment: so the problem is your database password or username maybe wrong

Comment: I've just checked and tried changing the pass of my db to the one I have in my php file. Still says denied user.

Comment: maybe you access the database from remote machine and your user privilege did not allow that. Are your web server and database server in same domain?

Comment: Yep. They're both hosted at webfaction.
Fixed is by using Shared IP address for server name instead.

Comment: It tried inserting a data to db but it was blank. only the AI for ID column was filled.